# Weakest hypothesis for integration by parts

Tags: calculus

I was wondering what are the weakest hypothesis for applying integration by parts to calculate $$\int_a^b fg \, dm,$$ where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

Is it enough that $f$ be differentiable on $(a,b)$, $f' \in L^1(a,b)$ and $g \in L^1(a,b)$ to write

$$
\int_a^b fg \,dm = \left[f(x)\int_a^x g(t) \,dm(t)\right]_a^b - \int_a^b f'(x) \left(\int_a^x g(t) \,dm(t) \right) \,dm(x)\text{ ?}
$$

Comment: the primitive of $g$ must also be integrable, no?

Comment: What is the primitive of g?

Comment: $\int_a^x g(t) dm(t)$

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Proposition**: Assume that $f$ is [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_functions) on $[a,b]$ and $g\in L^1([a,b])$. For $x\in[a,b]$, denote $G(x)=\int_a^xg~dm$. Then
$$\int_a^b fg~dm=f(b)G(b)-f(a)G(a)-\int_a^bf'G~dm.\tag{1}$$

**Proof**:
Since both $f$ and $G$ are absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$, $fG$ is also absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$, and
$$(fG)'(x)=f'(x)G(x)+f(x)g(x)\quad a.e. x\in[a,b].\tag{2}$$
Integrating $(2)$ over $[a,b]$, $(1)$ follows.    $\quad\square$

**Remark**:
If $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f'\in L^1([a,b])$, then $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$. See, for example, Theorem 7.21 in Real and Complex Analysis(Third Edition) by Walter Rudin.

Comment: Can you provide the proof of $G$ being absolutely continuous? Also what assumptions do you need to integrate the right side of equation (2)?

Comment: @Cantor: See [the same wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_functions) as given in my answer. There is a list of equivalent conditions of absolute continuity. In particular, (3) implies that $G$ is absolute continuous. Moreover, $G'=g$ almost everywhere. Since $f'$(resp. $g$)$\in L^1$ and $G$(resp. $f$) is bounded, $f'G\in L^1$(resp. $fg\in L^1$), so RHS in $(2)$ is integrable.

Comment: Remark is incorrect if differentiability is assumed only a.e. Care must be takn — always!