# Does almost everywhere differentiablty imply existence of weak derivitive?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does almost everywhere differentiablty imply existence of weak derivitive? What about the converse? If not in general maybe on compacts?

Comment: No, the Cantor function is a counterexample (differentiable almost everywhere, but not absolutely continuous).

Comment: @HansEngler ah, is abs. cts. the weakest that gives partial integration? I only need partial integration to hold a.e in order to get the definition of weak derivite right?

Comment: you're right of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hans counterexample and this question [Weakest hypothesis for integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345254/weakest-hypothesis-for-integration-by-parts) gives a clear picture of the situation